# How to implement server-side filtering w/ flex 4

Tags: apache-flex

I've got Flex 4, Zend and php. I've set up paging in my datagrid but how do I do server-side filtering? I have about millions of records so obviously can't do client side filtering...I've been googling all day w/ no luck. Anyone been able to do it or can point me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume to filter, you would collect filter text from the user and then ping the server with the 'filter text'; perform some form of SQL Statement on the data, then then send back the updated recordset.

Are you looking for something different? What do you mean by paging?

I thought that LiveCycle had some way to associate a dataset on the client with a dataset on the server to support the loading of data "as you scroll" through the list based class.  I did not think such functionality was available elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on the server side would mean simply sending some Strings from the client input source using a remote connection object to connect to java side.

On the java side use sql queries to retrieve the filtered data.

once retrieved send it back to the flex using dto objects or whatever and u r good to go.

```
public ArrayList calljavamethodtoSearch(String searchString){

    String sql_query="select * from TableName where name like(searchString%)";

    //execute the query and store data on a arraylist or whatever and return.

}
```